# How to generate a page layout using css where the page have, header, footer and 100% height content?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to create a page that is supported in IE8+.

I need the page to have a header and a footer each with a 100% width.

On the left, I need to have place to have a menu "with 100% height". to the right hand side of the menu, I need to put an iframe that needs to take the full width, full height of the center of the layout.

Here is what I have done so far

```
<div class="container-fluid container-fluid-override">

<div class="b_header" >
   HEADER
</div>

<div class="bodyBlock">

    <div class="left_menu">LEFT MENU</div>


    <div class="right_menu">iFrame should go here</div>

</div>


<div class="b_footer">
   Footer
</div>
```

Here is my css code

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-fluid-override
{
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bodyBlock {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
.left_menu {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  height: 100%;
}

.right_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 140);
  height: 100%;
}

iframe {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}

.b_header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; 
}

.b_footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I create jFiddle with my code http://jsfiddle.net/qgaLtbgg/7/

The problem with my layout is that if I remove the text "iFrame should go here" the middle of the page disappears.

also, when I try to put iframe in the middle frame, the left menu disappears.

How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I update it the following and it works now. I moved the text to left menu and still the layout is working.

```
.right_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 140);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of your `calc` function in inputed wrong you need `px` at the end. Since the menu's are `display:inline-block` i've added `vertical-align:top` to `.left-menu` for this to work, you can see in the example with the removed text that the right menu is still aligned correctly.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qgaLtbgg/17/)

(Note: there will be a space between the menus if there is whitespace in the html between the div's since they are `display:inline-block`)

Code:

```
  html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-fluid-override
{
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bodyBlock {
    height: 100% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.left_menu {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}

.bodyBlock {
    height: 100% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

iframe {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}

.b_header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; 
}

.b_footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.right_menu {
      display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 140px);
    background: green;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Hi the code still does not work. try to put a text in the right block it will case a problem. even when you try to add  <iframe src=""></iframe> to the green block it does not work

Comment: Inputing text in the right block works fine for me i've edited the fiddle recently so you might have used the old version try it again. What kind of problems are you having?

Comment: something does not add up. please look at this http://jsfiddle.net/qgaLtbgg/18/ all I did is added the right div on a new line.  I need to replace the green block with an iframe

Comment: Oh yes you can in the paranthesis at the top i've mentioned that, this happens when you have `inline-block` elements so the whitespace in accounted in the width, in our case when we do `width:calc` we need to be wary of that. Try increasing the width in the calc like so `calc(100% - 140px // increase this )` when you have a menu on the new line and it will work.

Comment: I increaded it to 144 and it worked. but when I put in iframe it does not allow it to take the full 100% width. Please have a look at my update jFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qgaLtbgg/21/

Comment: Just add `iframe:width:100%` since it dosen't know how wide it should be here is a [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qgaLtbgg/22/)

Comment: Thank you adding that working in the jFiddle. But when I move the code to my page, the iframe will not take the full height of he page for some reason. and the left column does not take the full height of the page

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong, there could be many things affecting the layout. Perhaps that could be more suited for a another question.